# What does it mean to solve an ODE by "going backwards"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Chapter 1 of Kreyszig's Advanced Engineering Mathematics, several references are made to solving an ODE by "going backwards". What does this mean in practice?

For example, chapter 1 (section 1.4) addresses exact ODEs & integrating factors.

At the start of the section we're reminded that the differential of a function $u(x,y)$ with continuous partial derivatives is:

$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy$.

and that if $u(x,y) = c = const$ then $du = 0$.

An example is then given for $u = x + x^2 y^3 = c$, giving:

$du = (1+2xy^3)dx + 3x^2 y^2 dy = 0$

or

$y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1 + 2xy^3}{3x^2 y^2}$

The latter is described as "**an ODE that we can solve by going backward**"

What does this mean? How might you go backwards to solve this ODE?!

All my searches using these terms wind up at the reverse Euler method, which I understand is a means of evaluating rather than solving the ODE.

Comment: It means that, if $y=y(x)$ solves the equation, then $x+x^2y^3$ is a constant. From that you can recover $y$ as a function of $x$. This is called an "exact" differential equation. See also the note by Gian Carlo Rota on the teaching of differential equations for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text draws an ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ by cancelling the total differential of a function, $d\,u(x,y)=0$. This is their *forward* processing.

Going *backward* is just the converse: turning the ODE in a zeroed total differential, which you can integrate.

Another example:

- forward: $x^2+y^2=r^2\to 2x\,dx+2y\,dy=0\to y'=-\dfrac xy.$
- backward: $y'=-\dfrac xy\to x\,dx+y\,dy=0\to \dfrac{x^2+y^2}2=c.$

---

Note that in the forward process, when computing the ratio $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, a common factor may simplify away. You will soon learn that it may have to be retrieved to enable the backward process. It is called the *integrand factor*.